# Entity Framework tables with no PK and table replication (peer to peer)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I want to add some sort of log for auditing where whenever the user changes some values I add an entry to this table. Right now I have an ID that points to the original table, plus username, date, operation, old value and new value.

Originally I was thinking that I didn't really needed a PK because it was going to be for the most part a write-only table. Querying this table would basically be for debugging and wouldn't really mind having no indexes, therefore no PK.

In addition to that my database will be replicated with peer to peer replication.

So I am using Entity Framework which complains that the table has no PK so it doesn't let me do writes on it. I thought about adding an identity(1,1) for a PK, but then the replication would start having issues. And I'm a bit lost on what to do next so I came here for advice:

1. Is there a way to ignore with Entity Framework if a table has no PK and let it do writes?
2. Should I use Guids instead of an integer for a PK?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm confused, as SQL Server Transactional Replication requires a Primary Key.

But assuming this table doesn't have a PK, you could:
  1) define a timestamp as a PK, or
  2) define a GUID as a PK

In both cases, you will have PK, but not so small as an int of course.

Take a look into this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24340/Breaking-the-Law-Primary-Keys-in-SQL-Server

It contains a good discussion about db design.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't need a real PK.  You just need to declare to EF some combination of columns that uniquely identifies a row.

You can even declare a PK to EF that isn't really a PK, but then you have to suppress the optimistic concurrency checks and never delete or update through EF.